# RuntimeError : Given groups=1, weight of size [256, 256, 3, 3], expected input[8, 64, 32, 32] to have 256 channels, but got 64 channels instead

Tags: conv-neural-network, vgg-net

I am trying to use pre-learned vgg19 and U-net together to learn, but I am a student who is having trouble with the following error. I would appreciate it if you could help me with how to resolve this problem.

If there is anyone who knows which part to fix and how to make the code work, I would definitely like to get help from that person.

```
def conv3x3(in_: int, out: int) -> nn.Module:
    return nn.Conv2d(in_, out, 3, padding=1)


class ConvRelu(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_: int, out: int) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = conv3x3(in_, out)
        self.activation = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)

    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = self.activation(x)
        return x


class DecoderBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(
        self, in_channels: int, middle_channels: int, out_channels: int
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.block = nn.Sequential(
            ConvRelu(in_channels, middle_channels),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(
                middle_channels,
                out_channels,
                kernel_size=3,
                stride=2,
                padding=1,
                output_padding=1,
            ),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        )

    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        return self.block(x)


class UNet11(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_filters: int = 32, pretrained: bool = False) -> None:
        """

        Args:
            num_filters:
            pretrained:
                False - no pre-trained network is used
                True  - encoder is pre-trained with VGG11
        """
        super().__init__()
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)

        self.encoder = models.vgg19(pretrained=VGG19_Weights).features

        self.relu = self.encoder[1]
        self.conv1 = self.encoder[0]
        self.conv2 = self.encoder[3]
        self.conv3s = self.encoder[6]
        self.conv3 = self.encoder[8]
        self.conv4s = self.encoder[11]
        self.conv4 = self.encoder[13]
        self.conv5s = self.encoder[16]
        self.conv5 = self.encoder[18]

        self.center = DecoderBlock(
            num_filters * 8 * 2, num_filters * 8 * 2, num_filters * 8
        )
        self.dec5 = DecoderBlock(
            num_filters * (16 + 8), num_filters * 8 * 2, num_filters * 8
        )
        self.dec4 = DecoderBlock(
            num_filters * (16 + 8), num_filters * 8 * 2, num_filters * 4
        )
        self.dec3 = DecoderBlock(
            num_filters * (8 + 4), num_filters * 4 * 2, num_filters * 2
        )
        self.dec2 = DecoderBlock(
            num_filters * (4 + 2), num_filters * 2 * 2, num_filters
        )
        self.dec1 = ConvRelu(num_filters * (2 + 1), num_filters)

        self.final = nn.Conv2d(num_filters, 1, kernel_size=1)

    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        conv1 = self.relu(self.conv1(x))
        conv2 = self.relu(self.conv2(self.pool(conv1)))
        conv3s = self.relu(self.conv3s(self.pool(conv2)))
        conv3 = self.relu(self.conv3(conv3s))
        conv4s = self.relu(self.conv4s(self.pool(conv3)))
        conv4 = self.relu(self.conv4(conv4s))
        conv5s = self.relu(self.conv5s(self.pool(conv4)))
        conv5 = self.relu(self.conv5(conv5s))

        center = self.center(self.pool(conv5))

        dec5 = self.dec5(torch.cat([center, conv5], 1))
        dec4 = self.dec4(torch.cat([dec5, conv4], 1))
        dec3 = self.dec3(torch.cat([dec4, conv3], 1))
        dec2 = self.dec2(torch.cat([dec3, conv2], 1))
        dec1 = self.dec1(torch.cat([dec2, conv1], 1))
        return self.final(dec1)
```